# Google glass: No icon in "ok glass" touch menu

Tags: android, google-gdk

I use GDK with API level 19. I trigger Activity on my custom voice command. Everything works well besides the icon in "ok glass" touch menu. The icon is not displayed.

I specify icon in my Manifest as follows in application tag:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
```

And also in activity tag:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
```

I also made voice command very short to check if perhaps there is no place for icon, but it is not the issue.
Anyone knows how to make it visible?

Comment: I noticed it happens just when you specify your custom trigger keyword. When using one from the list: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command
it works well. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed and will be fixed in the next update.  The problem is using the DEVELOPMENT permission... If you use approved commands then the icons will show.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed after update to XE19.1.